# How to make SeekBar take up full width of parent

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a `SeekBar` in a `RelativeLayout` whose width is equal to the screen width.

I applied `layout_width="match_parent"` to the `SeekBar` but it seems to keep some empty space on both sides of the `SeekBar` to accommodate the thumb.

I also tried using `android:thumb="@null"` The thumb is gone but not the empty space on the sides.

I really need to make the `SeekBar` width match the parent's. Could somebody help me with this? Maybe I could create a custom `SeekBar` class and set the width to the parent width in **onMeasure**(). If this is a possible solution, I don't know how I could pass the parent width to the `SeekBar` class.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the xml, is it native graphics you are using ?

Comment: Please show xml and screenshot of what you want as well as what you get.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to define following with the `SeekBar` in xml:

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

Comment: I'm quite surprised that this actually worked! Thanks a lot. I would never have thought of this because I never expected any padding to be there unless I have specifically defined it in the layout.

Comment: it doesn't work in API 17 or above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327246/how-to-make-android-seekbar-full-width-in-api-17-or-above

Comment: as @wrkwrk mentioned, if u put 
`android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
android:paddingStart="0dp"`
everything will work perfectly

Comment: Had to specify `android:paddingStart="0dp"` and `android:paddingEnd="0dp"` for it to work

Answer (score 16):

```
 android:paddingStart="0dp"
 android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me while the accepted answer oddly did not. Also you still need top/bottom padding to make/keep room for the thumb (which is usually larger than the bar itself) so imo this is the better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this problem in my app. The thing is, even though you didn't set the seekBar padding, there may be some paddings(*paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom, paddingStart, paddingEnd*) in the theme your appTheme extends. Set these paddings to 0dp, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before you post your xml,I guess that your RelativeLayout has lines as following

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

This means your RelativeLayout do not fill up the screen,seekbar is fill up in its parent layout(RelativeLayout).So you can not get view you want.

Comment: I have no paddings on the parent view. But thanks for your reply.