# how to make android seekbar full width in api 17 or above?

Tags: android, layout, width, padding, seekbar

I want to make seekbar full width with no padding.

I've seen this answer
[How to make SeekBar take up full width of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617132/how-to-make-seekbar-take-up-full-width-of-parent/25617286#25617286)

but in api 17 and above it doesn't work. there is a padding in left and right of seekbar. how do i remove this padding?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just set padding at run time and it's OK now!

```
musicSeekbar.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: We can't get equi-efficacious thereby setting the padding in XML?

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work using XML (API 17+):

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a parent layout before your seekbar's layout and put your seekbar layout in another one so that you can fill_parent